# how get laravel file manager image thumbnail

Tags: laravel, image, thumbnails

I install the Laravel file manager package in my app. but already I cant use thumbnail images in the blog.
How can I get an image thumbnail of uploaded photos when I use Laravel file manager?

Comment: Did You have any coden did You read documentation or waiting for ready code ?

Comment: @IProSoft
yes, sir, I search a lot but nothing was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching, I realized that such a function does not exist (at least until the time of writing this message).
I defined a function in the helper that returns the address of the thumbnail from the URL of the original image.
The reader should note that these definitions may differ based on the setting of parameters for another person.

```
    function LMFThums($url)
{
   $url2= str_replace(basename($url) , '', $url  ) ;
        $url2=$url2.'thumbs/'.basename($url);
      
          return  $url2 ;

 
}
```